# How to debug the threading in python , the behavior of python threading is very misleading

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, gdb

I have a process running on aws instance comprises of 7 threads. on running `top -H` command on linux based system it reflects residual memory as 7.1 GB. how to find which thread is throwing the error or because of which thread the speed of process is got very low.

After some time OS signkill kills the thread. the OS throws the error as +137.

Can we debug or attach any debugger to each thread?

Any inputs on debugging technique for the python multiThreading will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the actual code?

Comment: The code is very simple. the main thread adds the data in the queue and there are three or sometimes  five thread to take the data out from the queue and store it in redis.